# Mysql PHP LIMIT 1 Error

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I have the following code:(php)

```
$alert = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM 'user_" . $row['id'] . "_notifications' LIMIT 1");
```

which gives me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near ''user_2_notifications' LIMIT 1' at line 1

please help me fix this.

Comment: Don't quote table (or column) names using `'`... if you need to quote them, use backticks (`)... Quote characters (') are for string literals

Comment: Which bit of it do you want help with fixing? 

The part where you use data as table names? The part where you apply a LIMIT to a query without specfying an ORDER BY thereby giving unpredictable results? Or the syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the single quotes around the table name in your query:

```
$alert = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_" . $row['id'] . "_notifications LIMIT 1");
```

You only need to escape table names and column names if they are one of the [MySQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).  The escape character in that case is back tick (`) not single quote (') like you've in your query.

Comment: Or escape them like this: `\`foo\``

Comment: Thank you! This worked quite well. I have actually found this in many places in my code, and I have now fixed it!